# How can we make Stacked Bar Chart with Groups in chart js to combine the color/gradient for more than one data set?

Tags: chart.js

How can we make Stacked Bar Chart with Groups in chart js to combine the color/gradient for more than one data set?

This picture explains what I am trying to do...

[image]

So there are two datasets one for open tickets and another for closed tickets.
I want to make the color gradient like that in the picture.

This is what I have done so far

[a demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eztm7cy2/)

```js
const primaryColor = "#9CA3AF";
const primaryColorRGB = 'rgb(66, 199, 241)';
const grayColor = "#9CA3AF";

function maxValue(arr) {
  let max = arr[0];

  for (let val of arr) {
    if (val > max) {
      max = val;
    }
  }
  return max;
}

function getMaxValue(array) {
  var max = maxValue(array);
  if (max <= 1000) {
    return max + 300;
  } else if (max >= 1000 && max < 2000) {
    return max + 500;
  } else if (max >= 2000 && max < 3000) {
    return max + 700;
  } else if (max >= 3000 && max < 5000) {
    return max + 900;
  } else {
    return max + 1000;
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("ticketsChart").getContext("2d");
var openTicketeGradiunt = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
openTicketeGradiunt.addColorStop(1, primaryColorRGB);

var closedTickets = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 100);
closedTickets.addColorStop(1, grayColor);
console.log('ye');


const data = {
  labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
  datasets: [{
      label: 'Open Tickets',
      data: [8, 2, 3, 4, 15, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 11, 5],
      backgroundColor: openTicketeGradiunt,
      barThickness: 24,

    },
    {
      label: 'Closed Tickets',
      data: [0, 0, 12, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 12],
      backgroundColor: closedTickets,
      barThickness: 24,
    }
  ]
};

const ticketsChartConfig = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: false,
        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked'
      },
      legend: {
        position: "bottom",
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
          padding: 23,
        },
      },
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    },
  }
};

// ticketsChart
var elm = document.getElementById('ticketsChart');
var currentProjectsChart = new Chart(elm, ticketsChartConfig);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div style="position: relative;">
    <canvas width="400" id="ticketsChart"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script src="./main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What purpose does the gradient serve? do you need to add gradient to individual data points, like in your picture, or do you want to add gradient to a dataset, like what you are saying? I assume you have already read this: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/advanced/linear-gradient.html

Comment: Gradient looks good. Yes I want to add it to individual data points. That liner gradient documentation only contain single dataset. 
Let's say take Bar for dec data.
There are three 100 open tickets and 800 closed tickets. So there is blue color and remaining is gray. So that's what I want to do.
https://jsfiddle.net/eztm7cy2/ This is what I have done so far.

Comment: You would need to make a list of background colors and add to that list in a loop. check if there are any closed tickets that month, if not, then you add blue, but if you do have closed tickets, then you add your blue to gray gradient function.

Comment: But as I said I have two datasets I don't know how  to combine them...